# SQL Server: Pulling updated data from a function during a CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, cross-apply

Quick Summary: I have a function that pulls data from table `X`.  I'm running an `UPDATE` on table `X`, and using a `CROSS APPLY` on the function that is pulling data from `X` (during the update) and the function doesn't look to be returning updated data.

The real-world scenario is much more complicated, but here's a sample of what I'm seeing.

#### Table

```
create table BO.sampleData (id int primary key, data1 int, val int)
```

#### Function

```
create function BO.getPrevious(
    @id int
)
returns @info table (
    id int, val int
)
as
begin
    declare @val int
    declare @prevRow int = @id - 1

    -- grab data from previous row
    insert into @info
    select @id, val
    from BO.sampleData where id = @prevRow

    -- if previous row doesn't exist, return 3*prev row id    
    if @@rowcount = 0
        insert into @info values (@id, @prevRow * 3)

    return
end
```

#### Issue

Populate some sample data:

```
delete BO.sampleData

insert into BO.sampleData values (10, 20, 0)
insert into BO.sampleData values (11, 22, 0)
insert into BO.sampleData values (12, 24, 0)
insert into BO.sampleData values (13, 26, 0)
insert into BO.sampleData values (14, 28, 0)

select * from BO.sampleData

id          data1       val
----------- ----------- -----------
10          20          0
11          22          0
12          24          0
13          26          0
14          28          0
```

Update `BO.sampleData` using a `CROSS APPLY` on `BO.getPrevious` (which accesses data from `BO.sampleData`):

```
update t
set t.val = ca.val
from bo.sampleData t
cross apply BO.getPrevious(t.id) ca
where t.id = ca.id
```

#### Problem

I'm expecting the row with id 10 to have the value 27 (since there is no row 9, the function will return 9*3).  For id 11, I assumed it would look in 10 (which just got updated with 27) and set it's val to 27 -- and this would cascade down the rest of the table.  But what I get is:

```
id          data1       val
----------- ----------- -----------
10          20          27
11          22          0
12          24          0
13          26          0
14          28          0
```

I'm guessing this isn't allowed/supported -- the function doesn't have access to the updated data yet?  Or I've got something wrong with the syntax?  In the real scenario I'm researching, the function is much more complex, does some child table look ups, aggregates, etc.. before returning a result.  But this represents the basics of what I'm seeing -- the function that queries `BO.sampleData` doesn't seem to have access to the updated values of `BO.sampleData` within the `CROSS APPLY` during the `UPDATE`.

Any ideas welcomed.

Comment: It would be a bug if it worked the way you want. Halloween protection specifically prevents it. I haven't really looked at your query but you mention cascading so you may be able to replace it with window functions. But also you say this isn't really your query anyway so I'm not going to spend any time on that.

Comment: I hope your real world scenario is using a schema bound inline table valued function instead of a lumpy scalar function like your example! [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) for identifying the issue -- i.e. "Halloween Protection".  Now that my issue has a name, I did some research and found the [following article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2008/02/27/halloween-protection/) which mentions this specific scenario in SQL Server:

> ... update plans consist of two parts: a *read cursor* that identifies
>   the rows to be updated and a *write cursor* that actually performs the
>   updates.  Logically speaking, SQL Server must execute the read cursor
>   and write cursor of an update plan in **two separate steps** or phases. 
>   To put it another way, the actual update of rows must not affect the
>   selection of which rows to update.

Emphasis mine.  It makes sense now.  The `CROSS APPLY` is happening over the read cursor where all of the values are still zero.

Answer (score 0):

**The data is always coming from `@info`**

For input id = 11,  it will execute:

```
    insert into @info
    select @id, val   --which @id = 10, val = 0
    from BO.sampleData where id = 10
```

so from the `@info`, the `val` for `id=10` is `0`(which comes from `BO.sampleData where id = 11`), then cross apply, it deal with `id = 10 from @info`, which is `val = 10`.

everything is what it is in your UDF. And there is no update `val` to 27 when id = 10 from `@info` in your UDF,  **be careful that `@info` is the table get returned**.